Why won’t my macbook pro charge? There’s some magnetic metal in the charg opening. Is that supposed to be there?
My macbook pro won’t charge.

Is this magnetic metal supposed to be there or should i try to scrape it away?

Honestly that "magnetic metal" looks like it is under the plastic around the charging port. Meaning the port looks heavily worn. It's possible that scraping away that "magnetic metal" might cause more damage. If your Mac won't charge I would look at an expired battery or an issue with the parts of the Mac that charge the battery.

Ok, thank you so much!

Which model of MBP is this? How old is it? That looks like a seriously worn connection. Also, the bottom cover doesn't look screwed in correctly.
